# How to create fbx file from a numpy array 3D (x,y,z) by Blender

Tags: python, scripting, 3d-view

Actually, I am pretty newbie using Blender and I have some problems in my first project.

I have an 3D array with shape (10,100,100) they are Z,X,Y dimensions respectively. How can I display this array using Blender?

Below the image which is plotted with matplotlib in python and I want to plot once via Blender[image]

Thank you so much for your help.
PS To make this image, I just used a random array to generate it:

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(40)
data=np.random.rand(10,100,100)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have only little knowledge of programming, so I can't really give you the answer but instead maybe I can give you some directions from several links. Also I don't know how familiar you are with 3D modelling terms and concepts, like *mesh, plane, vertex, edge, face* etc.

Anyway, I read that numpy is already bundled with Blender, so maybe you just need to read the [Blender Python API](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/index.html) or read here first for [introduction to scripting in Blender](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/advanced/scripting/introduction.html).

Then from this [problem](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67517/possible-to-add-a-plane-using-vertices-via-python), and a quick read of API documentation, I think you need to read the [Data Access module (bpy.data)](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.data.html), [Operators module (bpy.ops)](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.html), [Mesh module (bpy.mesh)](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.mesh.html), and maybe some others then you can write the code to create that array of planes that you want.