# Adding a plane given 4 vertices in a transformed mesh

Tags: python, vertices, transforms, vertex-groups, coordinates

Given a mesh (i.e. plane), I have assigned 4 vertices (selected in the picture) to a vertex group.

[image]

Using the Python API, this mesh is moved and partly rotated by the bones. Now I want add a new (blank) plane within the 4 transformed(!) vertices. In other other words, the left upper vertex correspondence to the left upper corner of the plane and so on and forth.

I found a similar question here [Possible to add a plane using vertices via Python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67517/possible-to-add-a-plane-using-vertices-via-python). However, the location of the 4 vertices is hardcoded. Therefore, I'm interested in a Python code that gives me the transformed positions of all vertices within a particular vertex group.

Thank you in advance :-)